# How do i display a page ONLY after the iframe has been loaded completely?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I have a page, index.php, on my application that displays data from another page, weather.php. Unfortunately, the iframe takes a few seconds to load so after the page has loaded fully
(i mean the index.php page), the iframe space is there. So what i want to do is to make the page wait for the iframe to load completely before displaying the complete html.How do i go about this?

Comment: Do you have control of both sources? I.e., index.php (obviously) and the iframe content, weather.php?

Comment: yes i do. the weather.php is reading data from a data.json file but i don't think that matters. so yeah i do

Answer (score 1):

You can display a spinner until the iframe is loaded.

Below code can be used for checking the iframe loading status and remove the spinner.

```
var myIframe = document.getElementById('iframeid');
myIframe.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // remove spinner here
});
```

Comment: will the spinner be for just the ifram or for the entire page?

Comment: and where will i put the spinner while the iframe is loading?

Comment: it depends on how you want to display the spinner, i believe it will be better to let the spinner override only the iframe while it is loading.

Comment: can you show me an exaple of how to implement that?